# Example of "implicit ODR-use of a non-pure virtual member function that happens to be deleted"

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, virtual-functions, one-definition-rule, deleted-functions

There is a sentence in [the cppreference.com description of Deleted functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions):

> However, implicit ODR-use of a non-pure virtual member function that happens to be deleted is allowed.

Could you provide a code example of this case?

I tried to do this:

```
struct ff
{
    virtual int fd()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
struct ddff : public ff
{
    int fd()
    {
        throw std::exception("ttt");
    }
};
struct dd : public ddff
{
      int fd() = delete;
};
int main()
{
    ff* d = new dd();
    d->fd();
```

But it brings a error:

> Error C2282   'dd::fd' cannot override 'ddff::fd'

Comment: Virtual functions are considered odr-used even if you never mentioned them in your code. What the sentence is saying is that such an odr-use is fine with deleted functions. Your error comes from the fact that deleted functions can't override non-deleted functions and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78007471/example-of-implicit-odr-use-of-a-non-pure-virtual-member-function-that-happens?noredirect=1#comment137523784_78007471):

> Virtual functions are considered odr-used even if you never mentioned
> them in your code. What the sentence is saying is that such an odr-use
> is fine with deleted functions. Your error comes from the fact that
> deleted functions can't override non-deleted functions and vice versa.